# get os.arch() of the host

Tags: node.js, docker

Is there a way to get `os.arch()` of the host OS, from a nodejs app running inside a docker container?

I'd like to get some simple stats (cpu, mem, etc) of the host system (or maybe a remote system).

Comment: Why not run something like Prometheus exporters on the host then query from the container?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm working on a PoC and just want to see if that's possible.

Comment: There's rarely a reason to get host information inside a container. Partly because of security reasons